# Mvvmcross - Timer and ShowViewModel

Tags: mvvmcross

I am having a slight issue with using a Timer and ShowViewModel.

I have created a "Plugin" with a TimerService as I can't access Timer's in my PCL so I created a plugin to do this. It works fine calling normal methods but when I try to call ShowViewModel when the Timer reaches something like 5 seconds it throws an exception saying ShowViewModel cannot be found.

I can't seem to find a way to get around this problem. I might be missing some simple but I just can't put my finger on it.

Okay found the issue. I was working in a new dev vm and my nuget packages were set to stable only, changed to pre release to match my other projects and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Was using the stable version for this project where I was using pre release in all my others.